# CommonJS Require Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, require, commonjs

I want to reqiure my html but I can not do it. My code is so simple :

```
module.exports = {
  html: require('./template.html')
};
```

When I run codes, It gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\frontend\lokidump\server\views\traders\betofcourse\upcomingEvents\index.js:2:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `require` on a file it is expecting a JavaScript file, not an HTML file. If you want to load the contents of the HTML file into a variable look into [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)

Comment: Hi @JDelaney, so this can solve my problem ?

html : fs.readFile('./template.html',function(err,html){return html;})

Comment: @KamuranSönecek You will have to use [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) instead. That returns the contents of the file directly and does not use a callback